# How can i get only my messages from firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create profile page and of course profile page has to be just 1 person posts. So how we can write the code ?

My main page has all of people posts with this code :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return StreamBuilder(
     // stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Posts').snapshots(),
    
     stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Posts').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshotMsg) {
        if (!snapshotMsg.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshotMsg.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (!snapshotMsg.hasData) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                final dataMsg = snapshotMsg.data.documents[index];
                return FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('Users')
                      .doc(dataMsg.reference.parent.parent.id)
                      .get(),
                  builder: (context, snapshotUser) {
                    if (!snapshotMsg.hasData) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    } else {
                      final dataUser = snapshotUser.data;
                      if (dataUser == null) {
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      } else {
                        return homePageCard(context,dataMsg: dataMsg, dataUser: dataUser,);
                      }
                    }
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          );
        }
      });
  }
```

But as a said, this code has all of users posts. What should i change in here for seeing just my posts ?

( I tried to
`stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc().collection('Posts').snapshots()`
this code but it gives error... )

my firebase screenshots:
[image: my firebase screenshots:]

[image]

Comment: you need to pas into the doc(), the docId, so it knows where to look, `stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(**AddDocId**).collection('Posts').snapshots() `

Comment: thanks for comment :):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get only the posts of the current connected user you should use **Firebase Auth** :

```dart
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

// Previously get the current connected user uid
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;

// ...

// Get the post of the current connected user
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('Posts').snapshots()
```

If you want to get the posts of a specific user (not the one connected), just replace the uid of the current user.